# The ideal which is not principal in $\Bbb Z[i\sqrt{6}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

Clearly $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ is not a PID as $\sqrt{-6}$ is irreducible which is not prime.
Now we have to find the ideal which is not principal in $\Bbb Z[i\sqrt{6}]$.

I was trying to show that the ideal generated by 3 and $1+\sqrt{-6}$ is not a principal ideal in the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$

Suppose that $I=\langle3,1+\sqrt{-6}\rangle$, the ideal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ generated by $3$ and $1+\sqrt{-6}$, is principal, say $I=\langle z\rangle$, with $z=a+b\sqrt{-6}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. The elements $3$ and $1+\sqrt{-6}$ obviously belong to $I$, so they are multiples **in** $\boldsymbol{\pmb{\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{-6}]}$ of the generator $z$. Therefore we have that **$N(z)$ divides both $N(3)=9$ and $N(1+\sqrt{-6})=7$ in $\pmb{\mathbb Z}$, and so $N(z)=1$.** In other words, $a^2-6b^2=1$, so necessarily $b=0$ which in turn implies $a^2=1$, **so $z=\pm1$**, and in particular $\pm z\in I$, so $1\in I$.

Thus, we can write **$1=3(a+b\sqrt{-6})+(1+\sqrt{-6})(c+d\sqrt{-6})$, with $c,d,a,b\in\mathbb Z$, which implies $1=3a+c-6d$ and $0=3b+c+d$. Taking classes modulo $3$ we obtain $1=c$ and $0=c+d$,** we aren't getting any contradiction shows the result.

**I was also trying with $I=\langle5,1+\sqrt{-6}\rangle$ then I got $5a+c-6d=1, 5b+c+d=0$ taking modulo $5$ we didn't get any help.**

Can you help me from here?

Comment: But $\langle3,1+\sqrt{-6}\rangle$ and $\langle5,1+\sqrt{-6}\rangle$ are principal ideals. Try $\langle{2,\sqrt{-6}}\rangle$.

Comment: Also the norm of $1+\sqrt{-6}$ is $7$, not $5$.

Comment: How do you get that ideal so quickly?

Comment: You know, some of us have seen this problem before....

Comment: I have got it, thanks. If possible, please upvote